# How to get back to previous fragment having a single Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I have one Activity with five fragments. By default the first fragment is displayed when the user clicks on Submit, then the second fragment is displayed. However I don't understand how to get back to the previous fragment.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

add this code in your activity.

```
Fragment fragment = null;

switch (menu.get(position).name) {

            case "Board": {

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                fragment = new TabHostFragment(); // your fragment
                break;
            }
            case "Test": {

                fragment = new ScheduledTestsFragment(); // your fragment
                break;
            }
 if (fragment != null) {

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                    .commit();
        }
```

Comment: what should i add in fragment when back button is pressed

Comment: you should add this code only in your activity. not in fragment.

Comment: then how the back button will know on which fragment he has to go?

Comment: assume that.are you  in activity. then go 1st fragment , next go to 2nd fragment, next go to 3rd fragment. now you are in 3rd fragment. Then click back button the 2nd fragment will be view.